# Riemann sum problem

Tags: calculus, area, riemann-sum

I'm confused on how $2[4+0+0.4+1.6+3.6]$ is arrived at instead of $2[1+1.4+2.6+4.6]$

[image][image]

Comment: Add the units and compute the decimals.

Comment: Both what is written and what you are suggesting are exactly identical. It's just two ways of summing up numbers. You still get $2(9.6)=19.2$

Answer (score 1):

$(1+0)+(1+0.4)+(1+1.6)+(1+3.6) = (1+1+1+1)+(0+0.4+1.6+3.6)$